# cudaMalloc succeeded with static size but failed with dynamically calculated size

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I was trying to allocate about 2.75G memory on GPU. It's OK when size is 'static'(known when compiling), and if the size 'dynamic', it failed.

I am on a box with CentOS 7.1, Cuda 7.5, 2 x TtianX cards, intel 4790K, 32GB memory

The Code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

int main() {
    int item_count = 21217344;
    int dim = 128;

    unsigned char * data_dev;
    size_t mem_size = item_count * dim * sizeof(unsigned char);
    printf("memory to alloc %u\n", mem_size);
    int r = cudaMalloc((void **)&data_dev, mem_size);
    if(r) {
        printf("memory alloc failed!\n");
    }

    size_t mem_size_static = 2715820032; // 21217344 * 128 = 2715820032;
    r = cudaMalloc((void **)&data_dev, mem_size_static);
    if(!r) {
        printf("memory alloc succeeded!\n");
    }

}
```

Save it to 'test_mem.cu' and then compile it:

```
 /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc test_mem.cu
```

And run it:

```
[root@localhost test]# ./a.out 
memory to alloc 2715820032
memory alloc failed!
memory alloc succeeded!
```

So any idea about this?

Comment: In you printf use %d as your value is a SIGNED int and you'll see the issue

Comment: @MikeVine Thanks, now the code run with `size_t mem_size = (size_t)item_count * (size_t)dim * sizeof(unsigned char);`

Comment: My bad, use %llu instead. (I'm not sure of the canonical format arg for a size_t in cuda but that should work in 64 bit)

Comment: Great but instead of the casts it's be better to just use the correct types when declaring.

Comment: @HubertApplebaum You are correct! I modified the code and now it works fine. (sorry I edited it the second comment before saw your comments) Thank you all!

Comment: Someone please add an answer to this question so it falls off the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int item_count = 21217344;
int dim = 128;
```

Those are `int`s, and the product of those is 2715820032, which overflows as -1579147264. Requesting a negative amount of memory is of course an error and `cudaMalloc` fails.

What you want is to either declare those with a wider type (e.g `std::size_t`) or cast either components to such a wider type *before* the multiply, and everything will work fine.

Side note: you would have spotted the bug immediately had you used C++'s `std::cout` instead of `printf`, or the proper size format specifier `%z`.